# What is the purpose of x argument in dmvnorm?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

The signature of the `dmvnorm` function in the [mvtnorm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html) R package is:

```
dmvnorm(x, mean = rep(0, p), sigma = diag(p), log = FALSE)
```

In the description, the *x* argument is the vector or matrix of quantiles. If the means and covariance matrix is provided, then this should be enough to define the distribution, so why is quartile information required?

Example usage with 2d distribution:

```
cbind(map_data$X, map_data$Y)
x_mean <- mean(map_data$X)
y_mean <- mean(map_data$Y)
covar <- var(cbind(map_data$X, map_data$Y))

dmvnorm(x = ?, mean = c(x_mean, y_mean), sigma = covar)
```

What is the *x* argument for and why is this required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dmvnorm` doesn't return a function; it evaluates the density where ever you tell it to.

The x-argument contains the values at which you want the density function evaluated.

Comment: Any idea why they call the x-argument "quantiles" instead of "input to multivariate normal pdf"? Seems non-standard.

Comment: It's a suitable term to use when your writing an explanation that encompasses all of d- p- q- and r- versions of the function